# sandbox notifications encrypted after deploying a createinvoice.php/sendinvoice.php sample.

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, invoice

hi im trying to integrate paypal invoices to my site, i've installed the latest paypal-php-sdk and added my sandbox credentials in, when im trying to deploy a sample invoice sending, the notification i recieve in sandbox appears to be encrypted with base-64(image below), my hosting is godaddy and i haven't changed any code on the sdk except for the credentials and merchant/buyer emails. is there a solution for this problem?
[encrypted notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m907n.png)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'll venture a guess that you're seeing plain text e-mail notifications that are now base64 encoded.  I noticed this as well.  PayPal purchase notifications that were once unencoded plain text changed to based64 encoded plain text (not sure when this happened).  Your standard e-mail clients should decode and clearly display the message automatically.  If you're decoding programatically, Google DecodeBase64.